# Extraction of data from /AIF/ERR tcode

Tags: abap

I have a requirement to extract data from the `/aif/err` transaction code. I tried submitting the program of `/aif/err` with `exporting list to memory` but it gives an error of accessing zero object reference in the program of `/aif/err`. I did also try to use the class `cl_salv_bs_runtime_info` but it returns nothing even though upon checking on the transaction code there should be a data that can be collected. Is there any way that I can do this requirement? I am currently looking into the classes that was being used by that transaction code. Thanks!

Comment: `cl_salv_bs_runtime_info` works only on ALV Tables and ALV Hierarchical-Sequential lists. I think that `/aif/err` includes a tree display, so it can't work. I think you need to find specialized API.

Comment: Ohh, I see. What I did was to select the necessary details from the tables /AIF/T_INF_TBL and /AIF/STD_IDX_TBL.  Thanks!